# Using strpos to finds words in a string

Tags: php

so I am trying to check if a string contains a specific set of words, and set a variable if they do. I have the code below, first it was working great except that it would not work if one of the key words was the very first word, so I looked at the php manual and found out about === and implemented that, but now it sets the variable to one every time even if none of the words are found!

So basically it reads a text file to an array, the text file contains the key words, then it checks the string to see if any of those key words are present in the sting. If none of the key words are found then wc would equal 0 and so would inc. If it finds any then wc is incremented every time a word is found, and if it is greater than 0 it will set inc to 1 to flag that key words were included.

Hopefully that all makes sense....

Here is my code:

```
$inc = 0;
$list = file("filter.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$cnt = count($list);

$wc = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
    if (strpos($string,$list[$i]) === false) 
    {
        $wc ++;
    }
    if ($wc > 0)
    {
        $inc = 1;       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are increasing wc if the string is not found. 
You have to replace `===` with `!==`.

Comment: That worked thank you! I misinterpreted that